# Why cucumber-html-formatter cli throws error for a cucumber output in valid ndjson format

Tags: node.js, npm, cucumberjs

I am using cucumber-js 6.0.5. I want to generate a helpful human readable report. With the output of cucumber-js with legacy json formatter, I convert legacy json to cucumber-messages with npm package [json-to-messages](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber/tree/master/json-to-messages/javascript)

```
$> cucumber-js --format json:report/report.json
$> cat report/report.json |  ./node_modules/.bin/json-to-features -i cucumber-js > messages.ndjson
$> cat messages.ndjson |  ./node_modules/.bin/cucumber-html-formatter  --format ndjson > log_output.html
C:\Source\bdd-project\node_modules\cucumber-query\src\CucumberQuery.ts:200
           if (message.testCaseFinished.testResult.status === undefined) {
                                                   ^
TypeError: Cannot read property 'status' of null
    at CucumberQuery.update (C:\Source\bdd-project\node_modules\cucumber-query\src\CucumberQuery.ts:200:47)
    at C:\Source\bdd-project\node_modules\cucumber-html-formatter\src\cli-main.tsx:41:21
    at Array.reduce (<anonymous>)
    at C:\Source\bdd-project\node_modules\cucumber-html-formatter\src\cli-main.tsx:40:44
    at FSReqCallback.readFileAfterClose [as oncomplete] (internal/fs/read_file_context.js:61:3)
```

I tried to produce html from the ndjson file generated from json-to-messages using npm package [cucumber HTML Formatter](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber/tree/master/html-formatter) cli. But it throws error "Cannot read property 'status' of null"

I tried to run cucumber html formatter cli against another ndjson [file](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber/blob/0ba63412cb8624cc21d2313db7a1b622a10e2112/compatibility-kit/javascript/features/examples-tables/examples-tables.ndjson) which I took from cucumber repo. It gaves same error.

What I am missing here ? To generate html report from cucumber 6.0.5, Am I creating json output from cucumber-js correctly ? Am I correct in converting legacy json output to cucumber-messages using npm package [json-to-messages](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber/tree/master/json-to-messages/javascript) cli ?

How to use [cucumber HTML Formatter](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber/tree/master/html-formatter) to produce html report from ndjson file ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After installing cucumber html formatter globally as mentioned [here](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber/tree/master/html-formatter), I can successfully generate html report using global installation of html formatter

```
$>npm install -g cucumber-html-formatter 
$>cat messages.ndjson | cucumber-html-formatter --format ndjson > log_output.html
```

Answer (score 0):

I had to switch to the more recent scoped version of the formatter to resolve this:

```
$ npm i -g @cucumber/html-formatter
```